# Linear Model vs Random Intercepts Model

Tags: random-effects-model

Suppose we fit a linear model $$y_{i}=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}x_{i}+e_{i}$$
where $e_{i}\sim N(0,\sigma^{2})$. Suppose we also fit a random intercepts
model $$y_{ij}=\alpha_{0}+\alpha_{1}x_{ij}+u_{j}+e_{ij}$$ where $e_{ij}\sim N(0,\sigma_{e}^{2})$
and $u_{j}\sim N(0,\sigma_{u}^{2})$.

Is the OLS estimator $\hat{\beta}_{1}$ equal to $\hat{\alpha}_{1}$?

Comment: How are you estimating $\hat{a}_1$?

Comment: Maximum likelihood estimation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

Here's a counterexample in R:

```
library(lme4)

x = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
unit = factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2))
y = x + c(.1, .2, -.1, -.2)

print(unname(coef(lm(y ~ x))["x"]))
print(coef(lmer(y ~ x + (1|unit)))$unit[1,"x"])
```

The output is:

```
[1] 0.88
[1] 0.9333333
```